# Dynamic add Categories YII

Tags: ajax, forms, yii, submit

I have a form where user can create an article and select from dropDownList a category, to select category user need to create this before in category menu.

Now I want to add button near the dropDownList and where user click add, a popup is opened, with AJAX I need to do POST and after that to renew dropDownList from Article form.

What is the best way to do this with Yii ?

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly what you need to do. Write a jQuery ajax call that updates your dropDownList by adding child elements. Then write your "add category" popup. Once you have the two, you just need to call the function to update your dropDownList on a successful response. See this link for help with dependent dropdowns in Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/

Answer (score 0):

A very good tutorial of simple popup contact form is given in this website:

> http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/simple-modal-popup-contact-form.html

An Easy Solution for Dependent dropDownList Using AJAX:

> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/429/an-easy-solution-for-dependent-dropdownlist-using-ajax/